# Nested hashtable access in erb

Tags: ruby, erb

In an erb template, I access an element `(item.attributes[:Post])` which is a hash.

I verified its class by printing

```
<%= (item.attributes[:Post]).class %> => Hash
```

I can call general methods on it

```
<%= (item.attributes[:Post]).methods %> => works as expected
```

But I can not access any hash specific function.

```
<%= (item.attributes[:Post]).count %>  => NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
```

Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to print the value as `p item.attributes[:Post])` which is `nil`. `nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, which has no `count` method.

```
nil.methods.include? :count  #=>false
```

Comment: ah I understand I get called TWICE, once with an Nil object, once with an array ! that is why only very generic function work...

Comment: @nicolas looking at the error as you mentioned `item. attributes[:Post]).class` should be `Nilclass`, but how you got `Hash`? :)

Comment: Because I get called twice, for some reason : one with the correct object which I set up to have such a hash. and another time i get handed over another type of item, from I dont know where, and which does not contain :Post

Comment: @nicolas yes, I forgot that, :p